# NameValueCollection not grabbing first value of query string

Tags: c#, query-string, namevaluecollection

I am using a simple statement

`NameValueCollection nvCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);`

I am trying to grab the values passed in the query string.  A simple example of something passed would be

`form_id=webform_client_form_4&referrer=http://myURL/webform/request-information?agent=agent&keyword=keyword&full_name=Jon Harding&company=RTS Financial - TEST&phone=913-555-5555`

The issue I am having is that the `referrer` is actually the full string after it.  I do need the other values. In this case becauase the `ParseQueryString` splits the string at the `&` character the first value is always ignored in the `NameValueCollection`

Currently when I try to get the value of the agent it is a blank value, understandably.

What would be the best method to make sure I grab all variables? I could split the string at the question mark and then prepend an ampersand to the string before I do the `ParseQueryString`.  Is there a more elegant want to do this?

Comment: You have to encode the URL you send as a query string..

Comment: What would `nvCollection` expect to hold? just the parameters or even the base URL?

Comment: @KingKing the `nvCollection` is holding what I would expect just didn't think about the consequences of that first parameter. I'd like to retrieve the base URL and all of the parameters separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with least effort:

```
NameValueCollection nvCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString.Replace("?","&"));
```